# How to accomplish HTTP Basic Authentication with NestJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs

I am wondering how one can accomplish HTTP Basic Authentication with common NestJS Auth practices.

For example if I use an AuthGuard like this, I get the error

`(node:336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { compareSync } from 'bcrypt';
import { User } from 'src/user/user.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const b64auth = (request.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
    const [username, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64')
      .toString()
      .split(':');

    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { username },
    });
    if (user && compareSync(password, user.password) !== false) {
      request.user = user;
      return true;
    }
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    response.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Authentication required."'); // change this
    response.status(401).send();
    return false;
  }
}
```

I suspect, that returning false (and letting Nest handle the reponse) doesn't play with "manually" setting the response status code to 401 and sending the response.

How can I protect certain routes with this ancient http authorization mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest implementing an [`ExceptionFilter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) that listens for Exception thrown by the guard specifically (`UnauthorizedException`). Then, in the filter, set the response as you would like to, that way the guard doesn't try to send multiple responses and you can set up the response as you'd like.